# Javascript toggle link to show contact

Tags: javascript

Craigslist recently added a feature to their ads - "show contact info" - which toggles the phone number.  Does this tactic help thwart bots?  So simple, if so!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.

If the contact info is still available in the source code and the jQuery only shows that data, there is no difference for bots.

If the contact info is being downloaded via Ajax call from the remote database -> that's better as bots are unable to read that data.

Comment: It may be used for statistical purposes - tracking the amount of clicks on that link in order to investigate its usefulness.

Comment: Mike, that makes sense.  But if the ph# comes from a recordset field plugged into the script, wouldn't it still show in the source code?

Comment: Looks like the source code remains the same whether the link is clicked or not:

<a href="/fb/1234567890" class="showcontact" title="click to show contact info" rel="nofollow">show contact info</a>

So once the link is clicked, is it basically downloading the ph# to a layer over the link, or ??

Comment: @user3457264 It all depends on algorithm used by the specific bot. In most cases, they will just look up specific parts of code for phones and emails. If somebody writes var phone = XX; in the code - the risk is higher. If developers use API to access the data, it SHOULD be bullet-proof (if they use tokens/cookies or any other authentication methods). Typical bot won't even notice such a API call. But if somebody will write special BOT for one, specific site, then, the risk is bigger and only depends on site's security.